# i want to change UIButton and UIImage view by clicking on a button. But images for UIButton and Image view are different

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton

Hello I am new to Swift (Swift 3, Xcode 8).
i want to change UIButton and UIImage view by clicking on a button. But images for UIButton and Image view are different. Basically I have a Button and an Image view. What i want to is to click on the button and change the image view but at the same time button should change too (the button image is different from the image).

I have tried this

```
IBAction func testButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.testCircle = (self.testCircle >= self.circleArray.count-1) ? 0 : self.carbsCircle+1

        self.testImage.image = UIImage(named:circleArray[testCircle])
```

but here they come from the same Array, but if i use a different Array for the image, i am not getting anything.

How can i do it? Thank you very much guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got your question correct. You have a button with an image on it and an imageview. 2 separate things. And you want to change your images.

If you want to change your buttons image by clicking on it you should not only have IBAction but also IBOutlet for that button. Control drag and make an outlet for it. In the button's IBAction function just change your button's image to what you want, as well as your image view's.

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes you got it right. so basically. I have a button and i have a separate image view. By clicking on the button i want to change the image view and the button itself. But when i create the outlet for the button how do i access its image in code to pass it to IBAction?

Comment: In your IBAction function try accessing your IBOutlet. Something like: button.imageView.image

p.s. There is a good book for ios programming from the big nerd ranch. You should read it. It helped me :D